# Shell script to mail script output in table format

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am new to shell script. I need your help on below scenario.

Script: wc file1 file2 file3 file4

```
results :
1488 2977 2248 file1
123  345 657 file2
123 896 456 file3
567 987 124 file4
```

Now I need to mail this result in below format with header name

Here,2nd column is always default value.

```
Filename  Destname rowcount  bytesize
file1     default  1488    2248
file2     default  123     657
file3     default  123     456
file4     default  567     124
```

Please some one help me to write this script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ wc file1 file2 file3 file4 |
  awk 'BEGIN{print "Filename  Destname rowcount  bytesize"}
  $NF=="total"{exit}
  {print $NF, "default", $1, $3}' file |
  column -t |
  mail -s "table" you@host.tld
```

### Output:

```
Filename  Destname  rowcount  bytesize
file1     default   1488      2248
file2     default   123       657
file3     default   123       456
file4     default   567       124
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. i am not getting table content  to mail. only subject is coming.

Comment: Try to send you mail in simple cases and elaborate this a bit (there's tons of differents implementations of mail command)

Comment: thanks gile. Actually I need to send this output as a mail content.

Comment: My name is Gilles. Search the web : `send mail linux STDIN`